# How to skip rows in pandas dataframe iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

So I've created a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB9um.png) called `celtics` and the last column is called `'Change in W/L%'` and is right now filled with all 0s.

I want to calculate the change in Win-Loss Percentage (see `'W/L%'` column) if the coach's name in one row of `Coaches` is different from the name of the coach right underneath that row. I have written this loop to try and execute this program:

```
i = 0
while i < len(celtics) - 1:
    if (celtics["Coaches"].loc[i].split("("))[0] != (celtics["Coaches"].loc[i + 1].split("("))[0]:
        celtics["Change in W/L%"].loc[i] = celtics["W/L%"].loc[i] - celtics["W/L%"].loc[i + 1]
        i = i + 1
    i = i + 1
```

So basically, if the name of the coach in Row `i` is different than the name of the coach in Row `i+1`, the change in `W/L%` between the two rows and is added to Row `i` of the `Change in W/L%` column. However, when I execute the code, the dataframe ends up [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fc6Z.png).

For example, Row 1 should just have `0` in the `Change in W/L%` column; instead, it has been replaced by the difference in W/L% between Row 1 and Row 2, even though the coach's name is the same in both Rows. Could anyone help me resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: There is also the continue command in python which skips ahead to the next iteration of your for/while loop. You can do : if i%2== 0 ( or 1 for skipping even rows) : continue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution from this question here on StackOverflow.

[Skip rows while looping over data frame Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255174/skip-rows-while-looping-over-dataframe-pandas)